# Angular tr-ngClick event triggerd by nested checkbox

Tags: angularjs

I have a table where each row has a checkbox. The table-row listen to ng-click and the checkbox to ng-change:

```
<tr ng-repeat="box in boxList | box_expect:searchText" ng-click="openBox(box._id)">
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-change="checkBoxChanged(id)" ...></td>
</tr>
```

Everytime I click the checkbox, I trigger the ng-click event of the table row.

I changed ng-click to ng-doubleClick, but double-clicks on mobile devices are not comfortable to handle.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Considering `angular-touch` ?

Comment: I just want to keep my one-click event. I just want to konw, how can i prevent, that the check-box change event triggers the row ng-click event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a directive which stops propagation of the click event on your checkbox ([**DEMO**](http://embed.plnkr.co/ANeEPlPe3XJdZVtdfgiE/preview)).

```
app.directive('noclick', [function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind('click', function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
      }
    }
}]);
```

And add it to your checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-change="checkBoxChanged(id)" ng-model="loremIpsum" noclick>
```

Comment: That looks great, I'll implement this and check if it works for me :)

Comment: Yes that's it. I would never have thought of a directive for that. Tyvm ;)